# How do I prevent my threads from obtaining the same random number?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to make 3 threads generate random numbers, but they keep picking up the same number. What am I doing wrong with the threads?

Here is my "Driver" essentially:

```
public int[] GetOffers()
    {
        _3InsuranceCompanies guys = new _3InsuranceCompanies();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(guys.sellers));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(guys.sellers));
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(guys.sellers));

        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();
        thread3.Start();


        int[] offers = new int[3];
        offers[0] = guys.insurance_sellers[0];
        offers[1] = guys.insurance_sellers[1];
        offers[2] = guys.insurance_sellers[2];


        return offers;
    }
```

Here is the class the threads are using as a start method:

```
 public class _3InsuranceCompanies
{

    public int[] insurance_sellers = new int[3];
    public _3InsuranceCompanies()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            insurance_sellers[x] = new Random().Next(60, 200);
        }
    }
    public void sellers()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int price;

        // simulated negotiation. some threads might be good at negotiating so price will reduce
        // other threads might be bad at negotiating so price can possible go higher than before

        Monitor.TryEnter(insurance_sellers);
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            price = rnd.Next(70, 200);
            if (Math.Abs(insurance_sellers[0] - price) < 30)
                insurance_sellers[0] = price;
            if (Math.Abs(insurance_sellers[1] - price) < 30)
                insurance_sellers[1] = price;
            if (Math.Abs(insurance_sellers[2] - price) < 30)
                insurance_sellers[2] = price;
        }
        Monitor.Exit(insurance_sellers);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `new Random` out of the method and make static.

```
static Random rnd = new Random();

public _3InsuranceCompanies()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            insurance_sellers[x] = rnd.Next(60, 200);
        }
    }
```

---

## What's happening?

The following passage is from *Instantiating the random number generator* from `Random`'s [documenatation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8#instantiating-the-random-number-generator)

> If the same seed is used for separate Random objects, they will generate the same series of random numbers. This can be useful for creating a test suite that processes random values, or for replaying games that derive their data from random numbers.

---

Here's a little example:

```
var count = 10;

var randoms = new int[count];
for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) { randoms[x] = new Random().Next(60, 200); }
Console.WriteLine($"With many new Random()s: {string.Join(",", randoms)}");

var rnd = new Random();
var randoms2 = new int[count];
for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) { randoms2[x] = rnd.Next(60, 200); }

Console.WriteLine($"With one Random: {string.Join(",", randoms2)}");
```

Output

```
With many new Random()s: 70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70
With one Random: 70,89,114,197,89,117,176,64,61,103
```